# Asymptote of a parametric equation (with Arctan)

Tags: asymptotics, parametric

I need to find the asymptotes of a parametric equation. My book says you have a vertical asymptote when $y\to \infty$. But the parametric equation is the following:

> $$x= \frac 13t^3-\pi,y= \frac 13t^3 -2\arctan(t)$$

When does $y$ ever go to infinity? I thought about $t=\infty$, but the $\arctan(\infty)$ does not exist does it?

Comment: $y$ goes to infinity with $t$.

Comment: So apparently $y$ goes to $\infty$ when t goes to $\infty$ because $Arctan(\infty)$ is equal to $\pi/2 $. So you get $\infty + \pi/2$. And that equals $\infty$. So for $t=\infty$ there are 2 oblique asymptotes as $x=\infty$ and $y=\infty$ and u can choose $+\infty$ and $-\infty$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $$x=\frac{1}{3}t^3 - \pi, \ y = \frac{1}{3}t^3 - 2 \arctan t,$$
you have
$$
y= x + \pi -2 \arctan t.
$$
Since $\arctan t$ goes to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as $t \to \infty$ and $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ as $t \to -\infty$, your two asymptotes are
$$ y = x + \pi - 2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = x$$
and
$$ y = x +\pi - 2 \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = x+2\pi.$$